# Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING SSIS- Salesforce

Tags: ssis, salesforce

I am creating a SSIS packahe that send information to Salesforce.
However I am getting this error:
"Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value 11/10/2022 12:00:00 AM"

I think it is related to this column :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUCJP.png)
HoW Can i Solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need the right Salesforce DateTime format.
Read these answers maybe it will help - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BhO8QAK

In my case with PHP this helps.

```
$changed_date = date('c', '1664454080'); // "2022-09-29T12:21:20+00:00"
```